# scrapear imagenes de la web con bs4 y guardar en memoria(no en disco)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

quiero saber como teniendo el contenido de src de una etiqueta (img) guardar esa imagen en memoria

el scrapeo lo se hacer y ya lo tengo hecho,lo que no encuentro por ningun lado es como descargarlo en memoria

las peticiones las hago con el siguiente codigo de la libreria aiohttp

```
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            response = await session.get(url)
            html = await response.text()
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás haciendo las peticiones HTTP(s)?

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán estoy utilizando la libreria aiohttp, te pongo por aqui el fragmentode codigo :            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                response = await session.get(url)
                html = await response.text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente haz la petición a la imagen donde se encuentra la ruta y no lo guardes en ningún archivo. Lo puedes hacer así

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    response = await session.get("https://example.com/ruta/de/la/imagen.png")
    img_bin = await response.read() # aquí obtienes la información binaria de la imagen
```

De la propia [`documentación de aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#binary-response-content), puedes acceder al contenido binario (la imagen) utilizando el método `read()`. Sin embargo hay que tener cuidado con eso porque el método va a cargar toda la información en memoria, la propia [`documentación`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#streaming-response-content) nos advierte de eso.